# How to find span with biggest data-item using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with spans inside. They have `data-item attr`. How to find div with the biggest `data-item` attr. They are numbers starting from 0. For example I have:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span data-num="0">text</span>
  <span data-num="1">text</span>
  <span data-num="2">text</span>
  <span data-num="3">text</span>
</div>
```

Updated: This is part of my code, it's about uploading files and one of the input fields is multiple. And I show in a div with separate spans image names of the files. Use should add multiple files so I need to find the biggest `data-num` and increment it for the next file.

```js
function getFiles(document, window, index) {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.app-file' );
  input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
   {
     var fileName = '';
     var num = 0;
    
    if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 || $(this).next().next().html()) {
                    var fileName = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i) {
                        fileName.push(this.files.item(i).name);
                        var comma = '';
                        if($(this).next().next().html()) {
                            comma = ',';
                        }

                        divName.innerHTML = divName.innerHTML + comma + '<span class="image_name" data-num="'+num+'">' + this.files.item(i).name + '</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-file" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Remove"></span>';
                        num++;
                    }
                } else {
                    fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
                    divName.innerHTML = '<span class="image_wrapper"><span class="image_name" data-num="'+num+'">' +fileName + '</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-file" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Remove"></span></span>';
                    var maxIndexItem = $.makeArray($('#wrapper [data-num]')).reduce(function(result, item) {
                        return $(item).data('num') > $(result).data('num') ? $(item) : result;
                    });
                    alert(maxIndexItem.text());
                }
    });
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="file-name" data-input="corporate_document" id="corporates"></div>
```

Comment: Considering you could use a basic loop, can you show us what you've tried? We can point out what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span data-num="0">text1</span>
  <span data-num="1">text2</span>
  <span data-num="2">text3</span>
  <span data-num="3">text4</span>
  <span>text5</span>
  <span data-num="">text6</span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = [];
        $(".wrapper span").each(function(){
        var dataNum = $(this).data("num");
        if (dataNum != null) {
            arr.push(dataNum);
        }
    }).promise().done( function(){
      var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
     alert( $(".wrapper").find("[data-num=" + max + "]").text());
    } );
});
```

Refer [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrrtsteg/15/)

Comment: Thank you all, all snipets are working, but in my case this seems proper! :)

Comment: And how to check if `data-num attr` has value and then to push them into array. If there aren't data-num values, max is `infinity`.

Comment: I made a check after promise function -> `if (arr.length === 0) {
                        arr.push(0);
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can helps you:

```js
var maxIndexItem = $.makeArray($('.wrapper [data-num]')).reduce(function(result, item) {
  return $(item).data('num') > $(result).data('num') ? $(item) : result;
});

alert(maxIndexItem.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span data-num="0">text 0</span>
  <span data-num="1">text 1</span>
  <span data-num="2">text 2</span>
  <span data-num="3">text 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Should it be a function? I got this error: `TypeError: maxIndexItem.text is not a function
 

alert(maxIndexItem.text());`

Comment: Yes, but it's about uploading images and I'll update with part of the code where this is udes.

Comment: If you just run my code snippet above you should see alert box with "text 3" message.